# register-task-definition environment variables in separate jsonfile

Tags: aws-cli

I am currently registering a task definition using this line in circleci:

```
aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://.circleci/taskdefinition.json
```

taskdefinition.json looks like this:

```
{
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 0,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "cpu": 10,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "callback",
          "value": "myapp.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "apiurl",
          "value": "www.test.com/api"
        }
      ],
      "image": "<id url>",
      "name": "test-app"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "512",
  "family": "test-app-dev",
  "networkMode": "bridge"
}
```

I want to have the environment variables in a separate file like environment.json which is used when register the task definition. Does anyone know if that is possible?

Comment: I could not find a good solution to this. So I wrote a node.js script and used the aws sdk.